# How to automate the git pull operation from a private repository using saltstack?

Tags: digital-ocean, salt-stack

I am using digital ocean Ubuntu server for hosting . I want to automate git pull operation on my salt-master and minions .

Comment: Please make some effort by searching it in Google before posting question. If you have any specific problem when trying to solve the problem, edit your question by adding more details.

Answer (score 1):

I use this inside a statefile to clone a Git repository. You can than execute the state automatically when needed:

```
# Place a Git deploy key.
/root/.ssh/id_rsa:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://files/id_rsa
    - user: user
    - group: group
    - mode: 600
    - template: jinja

# Clone the repository.
git@github.com:user/repository.git:
  git.latest:
    - user: user
    - identity: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    - target: /folder/to/clone/to/
    - branch: master
    - require:
      - file: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```